# Always shows "Indexing" alert while continuously adding assets in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, assets

I am working in a Flutter project using Android Studio. When I try to add assets one after another to project, I am getting "Indexing" alert on every continuous asset addition process.

Here is the alert,

[image]

This happens even after 1 minute when I tried for testing. Specifically saying,

*Process -> Response -> Result*

- Drag & drop Image 1 -> No issue -> Successfully added
- Drag & drop Image 2 -> Shows the alert -> Failed to add
- Again drag & drop Image 2 -> No issue -> Successfully added
- Drag & drop Image 3 -> Shows the alert -> Failed to add
- Again drag & drop Image 3 -> No issue -> Successfully added
- .....

I have to spend double time for this asset adding task. Why this happens, even I try to add after 1 minute ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the assets you want to add and paste it into the assets folder instead of doing it one after the other.

if its an image, you can create a different folder inside the assets and name it  "images", then paste all the image related assets into it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need to add assets in different directory hierarchy (I am newbie in flutter).

Comment: Okay..right click on the root folder, then click on directory..  You will create a new directory

Comment: Thanks. I added all images at once and divided by creating directories as per need. During this time i didn't see this pop up. Anyway I managed to bypass this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to adding images to your assets folder through operation system. so you can follow below steps:

1- copy all images.

2- right click on assets folder and select 'show in explorer' in Windows or 'show in files' in Linux.

3- paste all images in opened window.

that's all.